# How to use a button in unity to go to different scene in different condition?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene-manager

In my unity game there are 3 levels and when a player lose any level a same "Game Over" scene appears having a "play again" button and when the player clicks the button I want the player to go to the same level which he has lost.

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
....
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
```

You can take the active scene with .GetActiveScene

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
```

Or with .buildIndex you can get the build index(int value) and add 1 one to it so the next scene is loaded. But keep in mind when you use the Build Index you actually have to manually add the Scenes to the BuildIndex, which you can find in the build Settings of you Project. If you dont want this you can also use this method to search for the name, but this isnt a good idea when you have like 200 Scenes. But for three Scenes that should be no problem.

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Level 1"));
//Replace Level 1 with the Level name
```

But there are also countless other methods, which you can find [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html), like loading a scene from a path.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Ok thanks, I edited the post now and will do it better in the future. You can see by my reputation that I'm not that long into development.